# python shell returns incorrect result

Tags: python-2.7

Type into the shell the following: `3 * 7.1` 
Python returns the value: 21.299999999999997

When the result is of course 21.3.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) to learn about the limitations of floating point math in binary systems.

Answer (score 1):

That complies with the standard for floats.  When you are dealing with floats you are not going to get exact numbers because of the way that a float is implemented using binary.  Think about it, there is NO Possible way to deal with a number with infinite precision.

See the [Wiki page on Floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).